# Microsoft .Net framework 3.5 SP1 Setup Fails

Tags: .net, frameworks, installation

On my Vista machine I cannot install the .Net framework 3.5 SP1. Setup ends few moments after ending the download of the required files, stating in the log that:

```
[08/26/08,09:46:11] Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0SP1 (CBS): [2] Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0SP1 (CBS). MSI returned error code 1
[08/26/08,09:46:13] WapUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0SP1 (CBS) is not installed.
```

First thing I did was trying to install 2.0 SP1, but this time setup states that the "product is not supported on Vista system". Uhm.

The real big problem is that this setup fails also when it is called by the Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Now, I searched the net for this, but I'm not finding a real solution... Any idea / hint? Did anybody have problems during SP1 install?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an article describing what might be your problem.](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2007/08/24/4548657.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced it on my XP.

I searched for it, and the result was that some kind of beta .NET remained on my PC.

There is a [tool to remove all](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2005/04/08/406671.aspx) .NET framework from the system. I run it and after it I successfully installed 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, though it listed error code 1060 rather than 1. I read elsewhere that having IIS turned off may be the issue, but this didn't seem to help. Then I read that windows update needed to be turned on. Mine was turned on, but when I tired to run it, it failed. I ran: regsvr32 wuaueng.dll which seemed to fix windows update. After windows update was working again I was able to install .Net 3.5 Sp 1. Note that I didn't actually run windows update, I just made sure that it could run.